# Not able to update progress bar in GUI (MainWindow.xaml) from another page User.cs running on a different thread using c#

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, xaml, backgroundworker

I have a GUI **MainWindow.xaml** where I have a **ProgressBar** which should display the progress of the huge comparison operation, the logic of the operation is written in **User.cs** page.
Basically, the **MainWindow.xaml.cs** is calling a method **compare()** of User class and doing the comparison and displaying the output at the end.

I have used **busy indicator** during the comparison which get hang and shows a custom message at the end.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

when I click the Run button :

```
{
    User compare = new User(Parser1, Parser2);
    busyIndicator.IsBusy = true;

    ThreadStart job = new ThreadStart(() =>
    {
        compare.compare();
        //above line calls a method "compare" of User.cs class and does the comparison and returns back to this page

        Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action( () =>
        {
            busyIndicator.IsBusy = false;
            MessageBoxResult result = Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show("Finished", "Generation Finished", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        } ) );
    });

    Thread thread = new Thread(job);
    thread.Start();
}
```

**User.cs**

```
class User
{
    public void compare()
    {
        for( i=0, i < 100, i++ )
        {
            int val = i; 
        }
    }
}
```

so how can we show the progress of `compare.compare()` in progressbar in GUI as percentage completion.

I have used BackGroundWorker but not able to fetch the progress of `compare.compare()`

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

### Part 1: Threading

You shouldn't use `new Thread`:

- Threads are expensive on Microsoft Windows (unlike on Linux where threads are generally cheap).
- Use the thread-pool, which contains threads that are already created by .NET and waiting for work.
- Using `Task.Run` will run a job in a thread-pool thread by default and represent the job as a `Task` object, which you can safely `await` because WPF's Dispatcher supports the `Task` Scheduler and will always resume on the UI thread after an `await`.
- Note that even though this means using the `async` and `await` keywords, this code is not actually "real" asynchronous code (unlike real async IO on network sockets and the filesystem) - it's just .NET *representing* a concurrently-executing background thread *as* an asynchronous operation.
- When using `await` in a WPF (or WinForms) context, it's important to **never** call `.ConfigureAwait(false)` unless you know it's safe to resume in a non-UI thread. (But it's okay to use `.ConfigureAwait(true)`).

It also makes your code a *lot simpler*. Here's all you need:

```
private async void Run_Clicked( Object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    User compare = new User( this.Parser1, this.Parser2 );
    busyIndicator.IsBusy = true;

    await Task.Run( () => compare.compare() );

    busyIndicator.IsBusy = false;
    MessageBoxResult result = Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show( "Finished", "Generation Finished", MessageBoxButton.OK );
}
```

That said, because `await` will re-throw any exceptions, you should always restore the Form's state inside a `finally` block:

```
private async void Run_Clicked( Object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    User compare = new User( this.Parser1, this.Parser2 );
    busyIndicator.IsBusy = true;

    try
    {
        await Task.Run( () => compare.compare() );

        MessageBoxResult result = Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show( "Finished", "Generation Finished", MessageBoxButton.OK );
    }
    finally
    {
        busyIndicator.IsBusy = false;
    }
}
```

### Part 2: Reporting Progress

To indicate progress information to a caller, use `IProgress<T>`. The type-argument of `IProgress<T>` should be an **immutable value or object** (i.e. a value-type like `int` or `float`, an immutable reference-type like `string`, a `ValueTuple`, or a custom class object with *only* `readonly` fields).

- I assume you want to report *only* a percentage value, so we'll use `float` (aka `Single`) for `T` (with values from `0-1.0` representing `0-100%`.
- I don't recommend using an `int` to represent percentages because it means the "resolution" of the progress bar will be too low (only 100 steps) rather than smoothly progressing from 0 to 100% with decimal places, e.g. 0.1%, 55.55%, 99.95% etc.
- If you want to return a `String` message with the percentage then use a `ValueTuple`: `IProgress<(String message, float percentage)>`.

First, change your `compare` method (which should be named `Compare`, btw) to accept an `IProgress<float>` and report progress back using `progress?.Report( value )` (use the `?.` operator to allow callers to opt-out of providing an `IProgress` object):

```
class User
{
    public void Compare( IProgress<float> progress = null )
    {
        for( Int32 i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
        {
            progress?.Report( i / 100f );
        } 

        progress?.Report( 1f ); // 100% completion
    }
}
```

In your WPF code, we'll use the default implementation of `IProgress<T>` in .NET called `Progress<T>` [which provides UI thread synchronization built-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1?view=netframework-4.8):

> Any handler provided to the constructor or event handlers registered with the ProgressChanged event are invoked through a SynchronizationContext instance captured when the instance is constructed.

Like so:

```
class MyWpfWindow
{
    private void UpdateProgressBar( float value )
    {
        this.progressBar.Value = value * 100; // Assuming ProgressBar's scale is 0-100.
    }

    private async void Run_Clicked( Object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        User compare = new User( this.Parser1, this.Parser2 );
        busyIndicator.IsBusy = true;

        Progress<float> progress = new Progress<float>( this.UpdateProgressBar );

        try
        {
            await Task.Run( () => compare.Compare( progress ) );

            MessageBoxResult result = Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show( "Finished", "Generation Finished", MessageBoxButton.OK );
        }
        finally
        {
            busyIndicator.IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: okay.. how do I show the progress of  `compare.compare()` in real time in a progressbar GUI ? Instead of using `busyIndicator`

Comment: @RDN Sorry, I completely overlooked the part about wanting to update a progress-bar. I've updated my answer demonstrating how to use `IProgress<T>` with `Progress<T>` to safely provide progress updates.